# salt ignore specific exit codes

Tags: salt-stack

I need to execute a local command with salt on several servers which returns different error codes then 0 and 1.

The success code could be 2 or 4 and failure is 5.

Is there any possibility to react with salt if a process return a specific return value?

```
test_cmd:
  cmd.run:
     - name: my_test.exe
```

Comment: Do you need to evaluate that command in the common state order itself? If not, there's a way to treat return values with Jina or plain Python.

Comment: I need to do this in the state and i figured out a way. You can store the output of the command in a variable like this:

{{ set output = salt['cmd.run']('....') }}

then you can check the variable